# Describing someone who is slightly overweight: “He is slightly on the _____ side”

Tags: word-request

He is slightly on the _______ side.

If I want to say that he is slightly overweight, what would be the most common word to insert here?

Thank you.

Comment: How about “overweight”.

Answer (score 1):

The word I would use here is **heavy**. There are other words that would fit, but *heavy* is the least offensive and therefore probably more common. See Farlex’s definition of “be (a bit) on the heavy side” (via [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+on+the+heavy+side)):

> To be somewhat heavy. This intentionally vague phrase highlights the speaker's awareness of or hesitation about the weight of something or someone.
> *Emma used to be a bit on the heavy side, but she's lost a lot of weight since she started going to the gym regularly.*

Answer (score -1):

Words you can use:

- Overweight
- Under-tall
- Too short for their weight
- Thick
- Fluffy
- Pudgy
- Out of shape
- Skinny-challenged
- Big-boned
- The list goes on